# Best location to install jquery and other plug ins using nodejs or wampsever folder

Tags: node.js

I inherit a pc with many applications all over the place and have just started using nodejs. Do use npm + Bower to manage plug ins and install it in the WampServer www folder or in nodejs folder. Some used to install plug ins in eclipse etc and many other locations. advise?

Answer (score 0):

npm and bower suggests that you install every dependency locally to each of your projects. I'll refer only to npm here, since I am not too familiar with bower.

npm essentially offers you two places to install your modules: Locally to your project or globally:

```
# Globally
npm install --global async

# Or locally to your project folder
npm install async
```

#### Locally to your project

If you have two projects in your `www` folder, your file structure could look like this:

```
C:
  www
    proj1
      node_modules
      myapp.js
    proj2
      node_modules
      myapp.js
```

(Which means you would be in your proj1 or proj2 folder when installing modules).

Also, it's common practice to include a `package.json` with each of your projects that list dependencies so that you can install them easily with `npm install`. More info of that [over here](http://browsenpm.org/package.json).

#### Global modules

Some modules (such as command line utilities) are supposed to be installed globally. This places them into your `%appdata%\npm` folder and also adds them to your path.

Installing globally is simple done by adding the `--global` flag as I showed earlier.

The question might have been a little unclear, so if I misunderstood your question, feel free to clarify yourself and I'll update this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try to analyze that and do a global install. I am sure there are many other alternatives. live and learn. Thanks again

Comment: Which specific module is it that you are trying to use?

Comment: Jquery there seems to be a lot of Jquery plug ins now in there but not certain if it is the main ones.